# iPhone app crashes after splashscreen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cordova, ios4, crash-reports

My iPhone App works fine on iOS 5, but crashes after Splashscreen on iOS4. (using PhoneGap) (using HockeyApp.net).

I am new for ios development.
I have developed an ios app with deployment target 4.0.
It is perfectly installed and working on iPad 2 (os-5.1)  and iPod touch ([4g] os-5.0.1).
It is installing on  iPhone 4 (os-4.2.6)  and iPod touch ([2g] os-4.2.1) but not working. It shows the splashscreen, but crashes after that.
I have addded my own log function in code and found that it is crashed before going inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

I am using HockeyApp.net to download the ipa file.
I am not getting what is the problem exactly, the following is my AppDelegate.m file.

AppDelegate.m : https://gist.github.com/4343470

The crash report:
Crash Report: https://gist.github.com/4343472

Please help me out this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is CDVCordovaView subclassed from?

Answer (score 6):

The crash is because `CDVCordovaView` is a subclass of `UIWebView`, and `UIWebView`'s `scrollView` property is only defined starting in iOS 5. Somewhere in your code you are trying to access the `scrollView` property, which causes the crash. Check if the `CDVCordovaView` object `respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)` before you access `scrollView`, to prevent the crash.